# How to controll the spinner item when switch fragment?

Tags: android, android-spinner

Fragment B has a spinner which has three item. I want to show the second item of spinner when i switch fragment from A to B .

I try to use singleton object to control it , but it's not working .

Here is my code , any help would be greatly appreciated.

My singleton object:
public class SetForTabPages {

```
int forBloodSugarSpinner;

public int getForBloodSugarSpinner() {
    return forBloodSugarSpinner;
}

public void setForBloodSugarSpinner(int forBloodSugarSpinner) {
    this.forBloodSugarSpinner = forBloodSugarSpinner;
}

public static SetForTabPages setForTabPages=null;

public static SetForTabPages getTabPosition(){
    if (setForTabPages==null){
        setForTabPages=new SetForTabPages();
        return setForTabPages;
    }else {
        return setForTabPages;
    }
}
```

}
My fragment A about switch fragment function:

```
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int id = view.getId();
            if (id == R.id.imageDetectionSugar) {
              sendSpinnerNumber(1);//i save the value as 1.
            ((NavigationDrawerLayout)getActivity()).switchFragment(Evaluation.newInstance());
//and switch fragment to A
            }
    }
```

Here is my fragment A:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
if (setForTabPages.getForBloodSugarSpinner() == 1) {//get the value 1.
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Enter here succeed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//i enter here succeed
            layoutForBloodPressure.setVisibility(View.GONE);//it's not working
            layoutForBloodSugar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//it's not working
            layoutForBMI.setVisibility(View.GONE);//it's not working
            //may be i should put the code about adapter for item,byt i do not know how
            compareSpinner(view);
        }

        //get spinner value
        evaluationEnterItem.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Object item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                spinnerItem = item.toString();
                compareSpinner(view);
                Log.d("name", spinnerItem);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });


        return view;
    }
//if i just click spinner to switch , it's working here
private View compareSpinner(View view) {

        if (spinnerItem.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.bloodPressure))) {
            layoutForBloodPressure.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layoutForBloodSugar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layoutForBMI.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return view;
        } else if (spinnerItem.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.bloodSugar))) {
            layoutForBloodPressure.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layoutForBloodSugar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layoutForBMI.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return view;
        } else if (spinnerItem.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.bodyWeight))) {
            layoutForBloodPressure.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layoutForBloodSugar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layoutForBMI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return view;
        } else {
            layoutForBloodPressure.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layoutForBloodSugar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            layoutForBMI.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return view;
        }
    }
```